# What does `if acct.activity[year] && acct.activity[year][month]` mean?

Tags: ruby, haml

I am trying to understand a line of code written by someone who is no longer present:

`- if acct.activity[year] && acct.activity[year][month]`

It is used in the following context:

```
    %tbody
  - x = (@today.year == year) ? @today.month : 12
  - x.downto(1) do |month|
    %tr
      - if month == x
        %td{rowspan: x}= year
      %td= Date::MONTHNAMES[month]
      - @customer.accounts.each do |acct|
        - if acct.activity[year] && acct.activity[year][month]
          %td{'data-transactions' => acct.activity[year][month]}
            - stmt = acct.statement(year, month)
            = link_to 'View', url(:statements, :show, id: stmt.to_s)
            = link_to image_tag('/icons/document-pdf.png', alt: 'Download PDF'), url(:statements, :show, id: stmt, format: :pdf), class: :pdf
        - else
          %td
```

The purpose of this code is to display financial statements by month and year. The strange thing is I can output the data in my console and it takes this form;

```
{10=>1}
1
{3=>2}
2
{6=>1}
1
{6=>1, 9=>1}
1
{7=>2}
2
{3=>1}
1
{2=>1}
1
{2=>1, 4=>1}
1
{2=>1, 4=>1, 8=>2}
2
{4=>1}
1
{4=>1, 5=>1}
1
{4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>1}
1
{4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>1, 7=>14}
14
```

It is there but for some reason it is not being returned. We had it working when using db calls to stored procedures however we are changing the project over to use an API and HTTP calls and since then it doesnt work. Here is where its declared and the puts generates the above in the console:

```
@activity = {}
@activity = response['AccountActivity'].map do |row|
  @activity[row['year']] = {} unless @activity[row['year']]
  @activity[row['year']][row['month']] = row['transactions']
  puts @activity[row['year']]
  puts @activity[row['year']][row['month']]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `acct.activity` would return a hash.  If you just did `acct.activity[year][month]`, and `acct.activity[year]` was nil, then you'd be doing `nil[month]` which would cause an error.

`&&` is `logical and` so if `acct.activity[year]` is nil then the whole test will just return nil, rather than error.  So it's a simple safety mechanism for when you're not sure what will be in the hash.

Comment: So the line i mentioned, does it mean 'if acct.activity[year] is null and acct.activity[year][month] is nil' do what follows else print out a blank td (removed the bit of code in the blank td as it was me trying to test what was contained.

Comment: Sorry, that comment is quite hard to read.  It means, basically, that if there's a "truthy" (which in ruby is everything except `nil` and `false`) value for `acct.activity[year][month]` then do the first chunk of code with the links etc.  Otherwise do the `else` part which just prints `acct.activity[year]` in the td (which might be blank, resulting in an empty string).

Comment: Apologies. I find it hard to read now i'm reading it back. So if that is the case and my data is returned in the console why is the conditional statement only outputting the blank lines. It seems theres a truthy so what gives?

Comment: You don't say what you're doing in the console.  If you're unsure about what's going on in the view then put some logging in there to debug the values, eg `<% logger.debug "acct.activity = #{acct.activity.inspect} %>`, then look in your log file to see what the actual values are.  You can then copy those to a variable in the console and step through and see what the if test would do with it.

Comment: Thanks. Will do and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `acct.activity()` returns a nested 'hash', it's often used to check that the returned `hash` contains the expected entries.

```
a = { :a => {}, :b => { :c => 2 } }

a[:a] && a[:a][:x] ? true : false
# => false
a[:b] && a[:b][:c] ? true : false
# => true
```